# What did Sebulba break on Anakin's podracer?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

Just before the [Boonta Eve Classic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boonta_Eve_Classic_%2832_BBY%29), [Sebulba](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sebulba) broke something on Anakin's podracer:

[image]

Later, Anakin had problem with his engines, probably caused by Sebulba's sabotage.

What part did he break? Was this piece carefully selected, or he just took a random one to mess with the engine?

Comment: It was the Plotonium regulator.  He actually fixed it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel)) names the part as an "***horizontal stabilizer***".

> Out of the corner of his eye Anakin saw Sebulba wander over from his
>   own racer and begin examining the boy’s. Hitching along on his spindly
>   legs, he worked his way around the Radon-Ulzers with undisguised
>   interest. **Stopping finally at the left engine, he reached up suddenly
>   and banged hard on a stabilizer, glancing around quickly to see if
>   anyone had noticed.**

later

> Again, Sebulba tried to regain the lead, pushing for an opening.
>   A**nakin held him off, but then one of the horizontal stabilizers on the
>   left engine began to shudder violently. A momentary vision of Sebulba
>   hammering on his stabilizer just before the start of the race flashed
>   through Anakin’s mind.** He eased off on the thruster bars, jettisoned
>   the stabilizer, and switched to an auxiliary mount. In the process, he
>   was forced to give way. Sebulba raced past him to take command of the
>   lead once more.

Answer (score 4):

The script wasn't terribly clear:

> SEBULBA bangs on a part protruding from Anakin's engine. He looks around to see if anyone
>   has noticed.